# Google Maps draw route without calling server

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a bunch of routes stored in database. When a user visits a page, I want him to see all of these routes on a map. I would prefer that the Google Maps server not have to resolve the route from scratch every time.

I would like to store the route and simply print it to the map each time it's requested.

I found the `Polyline` object in [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polyline) and it seems that calling `setMap()` draws the `Polyline` onto the map without talking to the server.

Does anyone know if/how I would be able to confirm this?

Comment: If you load the routes as google.maps.Polyline objects everytime the map loads, and you don't set their map property, then yes, those objects will be invisible until you manually setMap(map) for each one of them afterwards.

Comment: That wasn't my question. I want to know if rendering them on the map requires a call to the Google servers.

Comment: It depends on what are you storing in your database. If it's just origin and destination, then you need to ask google servers to pick a route between them. If you store the whole route google gave you, then the next time you can use that point array to draw the route without google's help.